# Another word for "Back"?

Tags: usability

The application has "sub-levels". Once a user dips into a sub area of the site, should "back" go back a page OR should back take them to the parent level?  history.back() doesn't seem appropriate in all use cases.

The application is web based accessed by desktop and mobile devices.

Thoughts on the table are "Back" and/or "Parent".

Comment: I may be missing something, but **Back** for previous screen, **Menu** for the parent screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you use *back* then the behavior os back to the immediate screen the user was prior to the current one, not the level parent, unless you specifically say *Back to Parent* (where parent is usually replaced by the parent name). Depending on he desired behavior, you may need one of these options or some variation of them.

As for options, since you're using sub-levels, you could use *"up one level"*, but again, this is if you actually go one level up. If you have some navigation where users can navigate through siblings rather than going to *sub-level, back to parent, on to sub-level again*, I'd strongly recommend you use *Back* since it's the most common word, the one that causes less friction and the one with the clearest affordance. **Return** is an option as well, but test it out because *return* is used in the **enter button** of some keyboards, so this might be confusing.

Anyways, the answer to your question is based on your flow, just analyze it and think how the user interacts with your app and you'll easily find it

Comment: These are all great points and you pretty much nailed how the team of 4 is split (2 and 2) so we thought we'd broaden the pool of developers. :) Its beginning to look like the correct answer is "Depends" :)

Answer (score 1):

you might want two options. back should take them back to where they were previously.

you could then have another button to jump to the parent.

another term you could try is maybe `return`?

Comment: We are considering "Back" and "Up" at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened to our good old breadcrumbs... 
I feel if you don't have more than 2 sub levels, you should go for breadcrumbs rather than depending on back buttons.

Comment: The application itself isn't "large" enough to need breadcrumbs and for the mobile view of the application, the screen real estate space is limited. But good suggestion nonetheless.